# is there any way to integrate mainframe files with Mongodb or any Hadoop component

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, hive, mainframe

I am using [Exstream Dialogue Pub](https://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/rep_ca/8/872/ENUSAP08-0118/ENUSAP080118.PDF) to generate PDF documents.  Next I would like to store these PDFs in HIVE or Mongodb and retrieve these PDFs when ever i want.

Is there a way integrate Mainframe with HIVE or Mongodb?

How to bring data from VSAM files to HIVE or Mongodb?

If not, please suggest any another component in Hadoop.

Comment: You are asking several questions.  MongoDB can run as a process on z/OS so it should be possible to store the files in a Mongo DB.  I'm not sure what the VSAM question has to do unless your trying to ETL the data and access from Mongo?

Comment: @Hogstorm I may be able to clarify. My shop also uses Exstream and we create AFP natively, but use a 3rd party software to convert that AFP to PDF (called ProAFP). The most common use of this ProAFP tool is done online via CICs, so ProAFP returns the PDF in a VSAM file. It sounds like OP is doing something similar

Comment: Yes, i want to perform ETL on VSAM file to extract the PDF files .
Is there any possibility to perform this operation in mainframe?

Comment: @SaggingRufus in our process we are converting AFP file to VSAM file. so in this process how can i get PDF's. if possible can you explain how to extract pdf's from VSAM file\

Comment: all you need to is write a program in a language you can run on the mainframe that will read in the VSAM file record by record and write those to your database table. What language is your mainframe code written in>

Comment: @SaggingRufus cobol... i want to understand how a pdf can be stored in VSAM file with AFP file data

Comment: @NagaKiran usually via a 3rd party software. The AFP needs to be converted to PDF before it is stored in the VSAM file. Like I said my previous comment, the VSAM file is only created when the PDF is generated online via CICS. If a batch job creates the PDF, it is stored in a sequential dataset.

Comment: @SaggingRufus in our batch process it is creating VSAM file through infopac pgm. if you are aware of infopac program can you please share some knowledge :)

Comment: sorry, never worked with infopac. If the VSAM file already contains the PDF, then all you need is either a COBOL program to read in that VSAM and save the contents to the database

Answer (score 1):

There is an mongo interface to VSAM. It's called Data Virtualization Service (DVS):
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS4NKG_1.1.0/kc_welcome_all.html